Start a forever thread with a expired objects loop, removing those objects, in rust
I am writing a service, and I want to run a loop forever that checks for some expired objects and removes them if too old.
pub struct Obj {
    expired: NaiveDateTime,
}

pub struct Maintainer {
    objs: HashMap<id, Obj>,
}

pub trait Miller {
    fn new() -> Self;
}

impl Miller for Maintainer {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let i = Self {
            obj: Hashmap::new(),
        };
        i.start_exp_observer();
        i
    }
}

impl Maintainer {
    fn start_exp_observer(&self) {
        let observer = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            thread.sleep(sleep_time);
            self.objs
                .retain(|_, o| o.expired.gt(Utc::now().naive_utc()));
        });
        // does this even work here
        observer.join().unwrap();
    }
}

In rust, this does not work, because I am using an immutable self in start_exp_observer, which is the one created by new().
I tried fn start_exp_observer(&mut self) but that puts me in trouble, as the Self created in new is not mutable. And if I define that Self as mutable, then I get trouble with the trait.
And if feels like the more I try, the more trouble I get (if I'd clone Self before returning the object for example, then I guess I am not looking at the same objects in the thread).
How can this be done?

You're going to need some sort of synchronisation (else what happens if a thread is using the map when your garbage collection modifies it?).  The simplest answer would be to use a Mutex<HashMap> but depending on your actual usage that might not be the most performant solution.

Great reminder, thanks.

If you need to mutate through a shared reference then you want interior mutability. There's multiple ways to achieve it, and which one you use can depend on multiple factors.

You need to make sure the self type can pass between thread, and limit only one access at the same time i.e. Mutex and Arc.
use chrono::*;
use std::collections::HashMap;

use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

pub struct Obj {
    expired: NaiveDateTime,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Maintainer {
    objs: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<u64, Obj>>>,
    //    ^   ^     ^
    //    |   |     |
    //    |   |     L The actual data 
    //    |   L To make sure only one access at a time
    //    L to make the data be able to pass between thread

}

pub trait Miller {
    fn new() -> Self;
}

impl Miller for Maintainer {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let objs = Default::default();
        let i = Self { objs };
        i.start_exp_observer();
        i
    }
}

impl Maintainer {
    fn start_exp_observer(&self) {
        // Clone a self, the clone will be sent to another thread
        let maintainer = self.clone();
        // Spawn a new thread, the `move` will move the `maintainer` variable to another thread
        // while keeping `self` in the current thread
        std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
            std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_millis(1000));
            maintainer
                .objs 
                .lock()
                // ^^^^ we need to lock the mutex, to make sure we do not have another thread
                //      i.e. the main thread, accessing it at the same time
                .unwrap()
                .retain(|_, o| o.expired.gt(&Utc::now().naive_utc()));
        });
        // Do not `join()` the handle
        // join mean await for it to finish 
        // because it is a infinite loop, the main thread will no progress
    }
}


Shared references can pass between threads just fine, they implement Send given the referee implements Sync The problem is the non-'static lifetime because std::thread::spawn requires 'static.
